# How to bind checkboxlist in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

i have **GridView** have one column is **CheckBoxList(Mon, Tues, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun)**

Data for selected Week:

- "1101000" mean (Mon, Tues, Thur is selected)
- "1000000" mean (Mon is selected)
- "0100000" mean (Tues is selected)

Below is use to identify the selected item

```
            Boolean isMonday = false;
            Boolean isTuesday = false;
            Boolean isWednesday = false;
            Boolean isThursday = false;
            Boolean isFriday = false;
            Boolean isSaturday = false;
            Boolean isSunday = false;

            if (alertDayInt >= 1000000)
            {
                isMonday = true;
                alertDayInt -= 1000000;
            }
            else if (alertDayInt >= 100000)
            {
                isTuesday = true;
                alertDayInt -= 100000;
            }
            else if (alertDayInt >= 10000)
            {
                isWednesday = true;
                alertDayInt -= 10000;
            }
            else if (alertDayInt >= 1000)
            {
                isThursday = true;
                alertDayInt -= 1000;
            }
            else if (alertDayInt >= 100)
            {
                isFriday = true;
                alertDayInt -= 100;
            }
            else if (alertDayInt >= 10)
            {
                isSaturday = true;
                alertDayInt -= 10;
            }
            else if (alertDayInt >= 1)
            {
                isSunday = true;
                alertDayInt -= 1;
            }
```

Comment: Why do you have 6 bits for 7 days?

Comment: Is 7 for 7 days 1000000 mean monday is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> selectedItemsDays = new List<string> { };
            if (alertDayInt >= 1000000)
            {
                selectedItemsDays.Add("Mon");
                alertDayInt -= 1000000;
            }
            if (alertDayInt >= 100000)
            {
                selectedItemsDays.Add("Tue");
                alertDayInt -= 100000;
            }
            if (alertDayInt >= 10000)
            {
                selectedItemsDays.Add("Wed");
                alertDayInt -= 10000;
            }
            if (alertDayInt >= 1000)
            {
                selectedItemsDays.Add("Thu");
                alertDayInt -= 1000;
            }
            if (alertDayInt >= 100)
            {
                selectedItemsDays.Add("Fri");
                alertDayInt -= 100;
            }
            if (alertDayInt >= 10)
            {
                selectedItemsDays.Add("Sat");
                alertDayInt -= 10;
            }
            if (alertDayInt >= 1)
            {
                selectedItemsDays.Add("Sun");
                alertDayInt -= 1;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that those strings are possible input data you want to convert to a `CheckBoxList` selection.  With Linq:

```
var sampleData = new[]{ "110100", "100000", "010000" };
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DayOfWeek>> selectedDays = sampleData
            .Select(str => 
                str.Select((c, i) => new { Selected = c == '1', Value = i+1 })
                   .Where(x => x.Selected)
                   .Select(x => (DayOfWeek)x.Value));
```

Now you have all you need to set the `Selected` property of each `ListItem` in the `CheckBoxList`:

```
var firstSample = selectedDays.First();
foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    item.Selected = firstSample.Any(day => day.ToString() == item.Text);
```

Assuming that the ListItem's Text is the english dayname. It's probably better to use the `int` value of the [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.dayofweek.aspx) enumeration as `Value`:

`firstSample.Any(day => (int)day == int.Parse(item.Value));`